# Left joining Mysql with link table and ORDER and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, left-join, linktable

I am developing a chat feature that has the tables `cases`, `entries` and `attachments`. Each chat (case) has chat entries that has one or more attachments. The attachments can be for example a text message or a video message. Now I am struggling to present the last chat message for a particular chat (case) in the chat overview - I only manage to get the last chat message of one of the chat conversations (the latest one).

The expected outcome should be a list of ongoing chat conversations with title and the last chat message, like:

> **IT-support chat**
>
> *I have solved the issue with the...*
>
> **Customer service chat**
>
> *It's easy, you just have to resta...*

Simplified table structure:

**Cases**

```
 id  |      title
-----|-----------------
  1  |  IT-support chat
```

**Entries**

```
 id  |    case_id   | time_created
-----|--------------|--------------
 15  |       1      | ...
 16  |       1      | ...
```

**Attachments**

```
 id  |   entry_id   |              payload
-----|--------------|--------------------------------------------
  1  |      15      | Who solved the issue?
  2  |      16      | I have solved the issue with the meatballs
```

---

This query picks just the last chat message for one of the cases and not the last chat message per case:

```
SELECT 
    cases.title AS caseTitle,
    last_chatmsg.payload AS lastChatMsg
FROM
    cases 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        entries.case_id,
        attachments.payload
    FROM
        entries, attachments
    WHERE
        entries.id = attachments.entry_id
    ORDER BY
        entries.time_created DESC
    LIMIT 1
    )
    last_chatmsg ON last_chatmsg.case_id = cases.id
GROUP BY cases.id
```

Any ideas of how to get this to work?

Comment: Please state your mysql version

Comment: *The expected outcome should be a list of ongoing chat conversations with title and **the last** chat message* `SELECT * FROM cases JOIN entries JOIN attachments ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @CaiusJard Mysql version 8.0.19

Answer (score 0):

Most recent chat per case:

```
SELECT x.case_id, x.id FROM 
  (SELECT case_id, id, ROW_NUMBER(OVER PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY time_created DESC) rn FROM entries)
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Turn it into a CTE:

```
WITH mrc AS

    SELECT x.case_id, x.id FROM 
      (SELECT case_id, id, ROW_NUMBER(OVER PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY time_created DESC) rn FROM entries)
    WHERE x.rn = 1

SELECT * FROM
  cases c
  INNER JOIN mrc m ON c.id = m.case_id
  LEFT JOIN attachments a ON mrc.id = a.entry_id
```